# Complex conjugate of a function defined by a contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\log$ be the principal branch of the logarithm, and assume that $-\pi < \theta < \pi$.

If $$ F_{n} (\theta) = \int_{1}^{e^{-i \theta}} \frac{(- \log z)^{n-1}}{1-z} \, dz, \quad (n =2,3, \ldots ) \ ,$$

how do you argue that
$$ \overline{F_{n} (\theta)} = {\color{red}{(-1)^{n-1}}}\int_{1}^{e^{i \theta}} \frac{(\log z)^{n-1}}{1-z} \, dz   \ ?$$

(The integration is along a line segment from $1$ to $e^{- i \theta}$.)

It's tempting to say that $$ \overline{F_{n} (\theta)} = \int_{1}^{\overline{e^{-i \theta}}} \frac{(-\log z)^{n-1}}{1-z} \, dz, $$ but I don't know why that would be necessarily true.

Comment: I guess you could use http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic119.html#p782

Comment: How did you determine that there is no imaginary part?

Comment: I thought you wrote that $F_n(\theta)=\overline{F_n(\theta)}$

Comment: If we start by $z\to \frac{1}{z}$ we get 

$$\int_{1}^{e^{-i \theta}} \frac{(- \log z)^{n-1}}{1-z} \ dz = \int_{1}^{e^{i \theta}} \frac{(\log z)^{n-1}}{z(1-z)} \ dz$$

Comment: Are you choosing the principle logarithm ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the principal branch.

Comment: I have my doubt about the answer , it might not work for $n$ is even .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get, assuming small enough angles and the principal branch of the logarithm:

$$\begin{align}
\overline{F_n(\theta)} &= \overline{\int_0^\theta \frac{(-\log e^{-i\varphi})^{n-1}}{1 - e^{-i\varphi}} (-ie^{-i\varphi})\, d\varphi}\\
&= \int_0^\theta \frac{(-\overline{\log e^{-i\varphi}})^{n-1}}{1-e^{i\varphi}} ie^{i\varphi}\, d\varphi\\
&= \int_0^\theta \frac{(-\log e^{i\varphi})^{n-1}}{1-e^{i\varphi}} ie^{i\varphi}\, d\varphi\\
&= \int_1^{e^{i\theta}} \frac{(-\log z)^{n-1}}{1-z}\, dz\\
&= F_n(-\theta),
\end{align}$$

or equivalently

$$\int_1^{e^{i\theta}} \frac{(\log z)^{n-1}}{1-z}\, dz = (-1)^{n-1}\overline{F_n(\theta)}. $$

Somebody messed up their signs (could have been me).